# BackgroundWorker not passing FileNotFoundException to RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm working on a WinForms project and at one point I have to load a XmlDocument in the background. I have a BackgroundWorker do this, but when the XmlDocument can't be found the BackgroundWorker throws a System.IO.FileNotFoundException in DoWork instead of passing it onto RunWorkerCompleted.

```
private void LoadBgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //---download manifest---
            SetStatusText("Downloading manifest...");
            Manifest = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            Manifest.Load(Properties.Resources.ManifestUrl); // <-- this is where the code gets stuck, it alerts me that the exception is unhandled
        }

private void LoadBgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Success = false;
                Error = e.Error;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                //---loading complete, close form---
                Success = true;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Am I missing something here? Shouldn't the exception automatically trigger RunWorkerCompleted so it can be handled there?

Comment: How do you start ThreadWorker? It's expected to have exception in worker's thread but it should be intercepted inside BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync().

Comment: Do you mean in debug mode? When in the IDE, common exceptions break the execution, unless you instruct VS otherwise. If you build as Release, an exception in `DoWork` will immediately terminate the operations and raise the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. There, `e.Error` will be set to the Exception type that was raised.

Comment: Yes that exception should indeed get handled by the backgroundworker and get passed to the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`. 
Like others pointed out, Depending on your debug settings, the debugger stops at the first error (the filenotfoundexception) and only when your press play or `F5` to allow the program to run again will the program handle the exception itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if you have the System.IO.FileNotFoundException "Break when thrown" ticked in the Exception Settings ?

It might be it, as backgroundworker DoWork catch an exception if thrown.

From Microsoft ([full article here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)) :

> Tell the debugger to break when an exception is thrown
>
> The debugger can break execution at the point where an exception is
>   thrown, so you may examine the exception before a handler is invoked.
>
> In the Exception Settings window (Debug > Windows > Exception
>   Settings), expand the node for a category of exceptions, such as
>   Common Language Runtime Exceptions. Then select the check box for a
>   specific exception within that category, such as
>   System.AccessViolationException. You can also select an entire
>   category of exceptions.

Comment: I wasn't aware that exceptions caught by the debugger could be disabled! Thank you!